# ¿Por qué mis tabs HTML pierden el efecto cuando agrego otros elementos?

Tags: javascript, html

estoy teniendo un problema con unas tabs que estoy haciendo, cuando agrego las tabs solas se ve el efecto sin problemas, pero dentro de ellas van imágenes, botones con ver más, etc y, al ponerlos, dejan de funcionar. ¿Qué estaría haciendo mal?

Aquí el código HTML, CSS y el JS (en este son dos, porque uno va para el botón ver más y el otro para el efecto de las tabs. ¿Estará aquí la falla?

He intentado de varias maneras, pero nada me ha resultado, incluso cambié el diseño de las tabs y nada aún, si me pudiesen ayudar lo agradecería muchísimo, feliz día.

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
  $(".tab-slider--body").hide();
  $(".tab-slider--body:first").show();
});

$(".tab-slider--nav li").click(function() {
  $(".tab-slider--body").hide();
  var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
  $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn();
    if($(this).attr("rel") == "tab2"){
        $('.tab-slider--tabs').addClass('slide');
    }else{
        $('.tab-slider--tabs').removeClass('slide');
    }
  $(".tab-slider--nav li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});

/el segundo js para el ver más/

function myFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: rgba(52, 95, 144, 0.07);
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.66667;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 3rem auto;
}

.tab-slider--nav {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.tab-slider--tabs {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  height: 35px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}
.tab-slider--tabs:after {
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  background: #345F90;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 35px;
}
.tab-slider--tabs.slide:after {
  left: 50%;
}

.tab-slider--trigger {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #345F90;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 11px 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: color 250ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}
.tab-slider--trigger.active {
  color: #fff;
}

.tab-slider--body {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.imagenfondo {
  width: 1184px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  Z-index: -1;
}

.subtitle {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 250px;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.ImagenAsuperPoner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40% !important;
  margin-top: 10%;
  top: 20px;
  left: 160px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.ImagenBsuperPoner {
  position: relative;
  width: 47% !important;
  height: 50%;
  margin-top: 30%;
  top: -600px;
  left: 630px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.P {
  position: relative;
  Width: 45% !important;
  top: -720px;
  left: 660px;
  color: #000000;
  z-index: 2;
}

.button {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #000000;
  top: -700px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  right: -630px;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#more {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="tab-slider--nav">
        <ul class="tab-slider--tabs">
            <li class="tab-slider--trigger active" rel="tab1">Tab 1</li>
            <li class="tab-slider--trigger" rel="tab2">Tab 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-slider--container">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab-slider--body">
            <img src="https://mainbrain.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Rectangle-102.png" class="imagenfondo"><img src="https://mainbrain.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Group-149.png" class="ImagenAsuperPoner">
      <img src="https://mainbrain.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Rectangle-105.png" class="ImagenBsuperPoner">
            
            <h2 class="subtitle">First Tab</h2>
            <p class="P">Nos enfocamos estratégicamente en el desarrollo web, SEO, optimización de contenidos y campañas, social media, email marketing, automatización, diseño,<span id="dots">... </span><span id="more">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span></p>
            <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn" class="button">Read more</button>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab-slider--body">
            <h2>Second Tab</h2>
            <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No entiendo... cual es el error? a mi me funciona a la [perfección](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/rNqaarR), solo importé el cdn de jQuery, dupliqué el tab de arriba y le cambié el id a `tab2`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, efectivamente veo que te funciona. Mi problema es cuando quiero pasarlo a Divi, no sé por qué me lee el script del botón ver más y no el de los clic en las pestañas.

Comment: Asegúrate de importar bien tus librerías, a mi me funciona tanto los tabs y el leer más.

Comment: Es un editor de bloques, parecido a Elementor, cuando yo pongo solo el primer js usando <script></script> todo bonito, perfecto, css y demás, pero al poner el segundo js, entonces viene el dolor de cabeza porque no toma el primero, pero sí el segundo, sale como la manito para hacer clic, pero no pasa las pestañas

Comment: Gracias, voy a revisar, estoy seguro que es un paso que está mal.